# When to use plugins.withType(somePlugin).whenPluginAdded

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

A gradle build has several submodules. Some of them have the java plugin applied, some don't. I'm trying to configure the plugin only when it's applied. To do this, I add the following in my top-level build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
  plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
    //some configuration on the JavaPlugin
  }
}
```

However, I also noticed the following style:

```
allprojects {
  plugins.withType(JavaPlugin).whenPluginAdded {
    //some configuration on the JavaPlugin
  }
}
```

What's the difference between the 2. When do I use the `withType(){}`-style configuration and when do I use the `withType().whenPluginAdded{}`-style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `whenPluginAdded()` it invokes `whenObjectAdded()` on the current collection. And when you call `withType()` and pass a `Closure`, it invokes `all()` on the current collection, which in its turn calls `whenObjectAdded()` on a copied collection.

So both these methods do the same thing but the former makes a defensive copy of a plugin collection.

Comment: So, if I would like to configure the java plugin by specifying things like the encoding, the java version, etc..., it doesn't really make any difference. Correct?

Comment: As far as I understand from Gradle sources it doesn't make any difference.